# How do I escape parentheses in DAX?

Tags: escaping, dax

I need to include opening and closing parentheses in a FILTER statement in DAX, because the text I am looking for in the column to filter by contains parentheses like this:

FILTER(MyTable,MyTable[MyColumn]="Data Expression (DAX)"

This does not work, because the parentheses are reserved characters and DAX thinks I want to encase the text in parentheses as an operator preference. I have searched all over, and the only things I have found is escape for non-printing characters (cr, lf), using #() OR #(cr), #(lf) syntax, which does not seem to work for parentheses, as I tried #(0028) and #(0029).

Even the DAX reference does not mention how to do this, as I have read and re-read it several times (unless I am missing something obscure somewhere).

Any help in this is much appreciated, as I do not want to have to create a calculated column to convert all them to remove the parentheses around the text, so please tell me there is a way to do this. Also, to change the source to remove the parentheses is a non-starter, as it would be an organization-wide change that would break other stuff in the process.

Thanks much.

Comment: I've tested this in Power BI and it works fine without any escaping necessary. What error are you getting when you try it?

Comment: It wasn't giving me an error, it just was not filtering properly. I just retyped it and tried it again, and it works now... odd. Oh well, thanks for responding, sorry for the churn.